# Yii2 AccessControl - Strange behavior for deny access

Tags: php, yii2

I want to deny access to the controller for certain roles.

So I write the rule:

```
'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                  //  'actions' => null,
                    'allow' => false,
                    'roles' => ['designer'],
                ],
              ],
           ],
```

Despite that my role is *admin*, it throw 403.

Of course, I could write the opposite:

```
'allow' => true,
'roles' => ['admin', 'seller'],
```

But I want to understand why the first case does not work.

Comment: are you using simple RBAC or advanced how are you saving the roles of the users?

Comment: Yes, default RBAC. The correct solution is below, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deduce from [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) that when you use `AccessControl`, all the present rules are evaluated sequentially. The first rule that matches the request is triggered, and it determines what happens with it. At the end, if no rule is triggered, the request is denied by default. Therefore, if you only want to restrict 1 role and accept everything else, you should add an `allow` rule with no conditions after your `deny` rule.